Flag history page is missing the top bar on mobile Chrome
Flag history page is missing the top bar on mobile Chrome. Example:

Tested on Chrome with Android on a Galaxy S23, with a Chrome default zoom level of 100%.

Turns out that one has to zoom out:

Still not great though.

@PeterJames thanks, got it, I had to zoom out https://i.sstatic.net/xFS6lRYi.png only page where one needs to zoom out to see the top bar afaik. (At least I had to on my Samsung Galaxy S23). I also use Chrome 129.0.6668.81

@PeterJames chrome zoom out

@PeterJames thanks yes I meant zooming by pinching your fingers on the screen and dragging: https://i.sstatic.net/6sAM0vBM.png. Sorry I thought that was a Chrome zoom but in hindsight I don't know

Actually, I can replicate this issue by adjusting the zoom settings in the Accessibility menu of Chrome and indeed the menu buttons only disappear on the Flag History. Other tabs seem to work as expected. On my device, I can actually see the buttons appear (with a flash) when refreshing the page and then disappearing (presumably off to the right)

I don't think it's a bug, SE (and likely most sites) never supported browsers zoom, which naturally mess up the design. No idea why it affects only that page, but anyway to have the design working properly, one has to use the default zoom level of the browser.

@ShadowWizard I use the default zoom level

So your default is most likely over 100%, as @PeterJames can also likely verify. When I changed the zoom (in the mobile Chrome settings) from 100% to e.g. 150% I could also replicate what you see. Guess I meant "one has to use zoom level of 100% in the browser", sorry for misleading.

@ShadowWizard thanks, my Chrome default zoom level is 100%

@ShadowWizard Actually, I think it may have more to do with a setting in chrome Accessibility menu titled "Force enable zoom" which "overrides a website's request to prevent zooming in" When I turn that on and off, the top bar appears and disappears ... irrespective of the zoom level, even at 100%, but in fact it does not really disappear, as I am only being shown the left half of the page. But because of the layout of the flag history the left half of the page looks complete. I suspect that the problem is caused by the post title not wrapping properly forcing the page to be wider than normal

@PeterJames good catch, you're right, when "Force enable zoom" is on, the issue is present. When "Force enable zoom" is off, the issue is absent.

When you turn "Force enable zoom" on and off in the Accessibility menu of Chrome's settings on Android, you can clearly demonstrate this issue as described in the comments of your question.
The problem is caused by the post title of the post in the flag listing not wrapping properly.

When inspecting the CSS classes, we can see a class "answer-link" and if we change this to "s-link" which is the class used in the question page listing, we see that the title wraps properly.

I suspect that further investigation will prove that this is a bug in the listing of the flag history as the post titles should not extend rightwards past the div boundary.
N.B. These screenshots were taken on a desktop in Chrome using the developer tools with mobile device selected. The zoom "bug" issue does not replicate in developer tools on a desktop, but the problem with the post titles is clearly visible
